# how to replace xml value using xls taking replace value input from a file

Tags: python, xml, shell, xslt, sed

I have a xml file which has same tag in multiple places in that file.I want to change the contains by taking input from file. Below is my xml file i want to change, the value present in between VL -- /VL by taking input from a file. Input file contains value serially. It ok to change value serially ?
I am very new to xls so not getting from where to start. Any input will help me.

```
<VL>
    <vl-id>VL</vl-id>
    <idx>1</idx>
    <type>flat</type>
    <link>true_c</link>
    <properties>
        <Ip>IPv4</Ip>
        <network-creation-type>existing_c</network-creation-type>
        <existing-segmentation-id>sgn-1234-abcd-efgh-5670</existing-segmentation-id>
        <existing-network-name>Ve_VNF_NET_ID</existing-network-name>
        <existing-network-id>ef923747-ea0a-4306-9063-b73237103349</existing-network-id>
        <existing-subnet-name>Ve_VNF_NET_ID_subnet</existing-subnet-name>
        <existing-physical-network>private_c</existing-physical-network>
        <existing-subnet-id>5a94bcbd-ae6c-4cca-8ea9-6d50d7be2f37</existing-subnet-id>
        <is-ip-migration-required>migration_not_required_c</is-ip-migration-required>
    </properties>
</VL>
<VL>
    <vl-id>VL</vl-id>
    <idx>1</idx>
    <type>flat</type>
    <link>true_c</link>
    <properties>
        <Ip>IPv4</Ip>
        <network-creation-type>existing_c</network-creation-type>
        <existing-segmentation-id>sgn-1234-abcd-efgh-5670</existing-segmentation-id>
        <existing-network-name>external_161</existing-network-name>
        <existing-network-id>2a05dc5e-d34c-4940-8fa2-6ba699e0e253</existing-network-id>
        <existing-subnet-name>external_161_subnet</existing-subnet-name>
        <existing-physical-network>private_c</existing-physical-network>
        <existing-subnet-id>bd4b7b3e-c878-417a-8d3c-8c7f367f9653</existing-subnet-id>
        <is-ip-migration-required>migration_required_c</is-ip-migration-required>
    </properties>
</VL>
```

Comment: `<id>VL</vl-id>` is not well-formed XML.

Comment: corrected the tag

Comment: *xls* is the older Excel spreadsheet formats. Did you mean XSLT? And please provide example of input file. Even your attempted Python code. And what exactly within the *VL* tags do you want to change?

Comment: Yes i mean xslt. I have a main file which has multiple VL Tags. I want to replace all the contains inside the VL Tag by using a input file. Input file contains same tag but updated values only.

Comment: Can you share the input file too? If the main file and input file are similar w.r.t. tags, structure and the only difference is the values, why is the transformation required? You can directly use the input XML file in your code.

Comment: My main file has VL tag Info along with other info .this vl tag comes in middle of that file.yes you are right here only value changed which I am getting from query.i need to update main file with this new value.shell script is not useful on this so thought of using xls.any input help me.